# Is it possible to summarize conditional named dynamic imports iteratively in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I would like to programmatically simplify the following named imports and assignments in order to avoid repetition and was wondering if there is a way to do this with the help of a loop.

What I have at the moment:

```js
import { globalLocale } from './i18n'

let locale, dateLocale

if (globalLocale === 'de-DE') {
  const { dateDeDE, deDE } = await import('node_module')

  locale = deDE
  dateLocale = dateDeDE
} else if (globalLocale === 'fr-FR') {
  const { dateFrFR, frFR } = await import('node_module')

  locale = frFR
  dateLocale = dateFrFR
} else {
  const { dateEnUS, enUS } = await import('node_module')

  locale = enUS
  dateLocale = dateEnUS
}
```

Is it possible to summarize the above with the help of a loop like this:

```js
import { globalLocale } from './i18n'

let locale, dateLocale

const locales = {
  'de-DE': ['deDE', 'dateDeDE']
  'fr-FR': ['frFR', 'dateFrFR']
  'en-US': ['enUS', 'dateEnUS']
}

for (let lang in locales) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(locales, lang)) {
    if (globalLocale === lang) {
      const { [locales[lang][0]]: currentLocale, [locales[lang][1]]: currentDateLocale  } = await import('node_module')

      locale = currentLocale
      dateLocale = currentDateLocale
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT** & Addition to the accepted answer:
If you are using TS - In TypeScript you will have to derive the types from the module instance itself:

```js
import { globalLocale } from './i18n'
import { Language } from './models'
import { TDateLocale, TLocale } from 'node_module'

const locales: { [key in keyof Language]: string[] } = {
  'de-DE': ['deDE', 'dateDeDE'],
  'fr-FR': ['frFR', 'dateFrFR'],
}

const moduleLocales = locales[globalLocale as keyof Language] ?? ['enUS', 'dateEnUS']

const module = await import('node_module')

const locale = module[moduleLocales[0] as keyof typeof module] as TLocale
const dateLocale = module[moduleLocales[1] as keyof typeof module] as TDateLocale
```

Comment: This seems overly-complicated. Import the module and reference the locale directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve keys from a map of locales to keys, and default to `enUS`/`dateEnUS`  if the entry for a locale doesn't exist. You also don't really need to destructure the keys out of the imported module. We could just do it "the old fashioned way":

```js
import { globalLocale } from './i18n';

const locales = {
  'de-DE': ['deDE', 'dateDeDE'],
  'fr-FR': ['frFR', 'dateFrFR'],
  // 'en-US': ['enUS', 'dateEnUS'], // default
};

// default to enUS if the globalLocale doesn't exist 
const keys = locales[globalLocale] ?? ['enUS', 'dateEnUS'];

const module = await import('node_module');

const locale = module[keys[0]];
const dateLocale = module[keys[1]];
```

but if you really want to use destructuring that bad, I suppose you could:

```js
// const [locale, dateLocale] = keys.map((key) => module[key]);
const [locale, dateLocale] = [module[keys[0]], module[keys[1]]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked nicely. I was not aware that you could retrieve the exported vars of the module via it's objects keys. But makes absolutely more sense this way.